# Cast from 'String?!' to unrelated type '[[String : AnyObject]]' always fails

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have code which works fine and throws no warnings to parse some JSON from my server. It runs and returns the values in the console without issue until I try to import the AWSNS framework, whereupon it gives me the warning in the title and crashes upon run saying "-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". Any ideas why this might be failing when I import Amazon's SNS framework?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AWSSNS

class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.getEvents()
}
func getEvents(){
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/mydirectory/JSONFile")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("File downloaded successfully.")
            do{
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)
                if let events = json["events"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for event in events {
                        if let eventName = event["eventName"] as? String {
                            if let day = event["day"] as? String {
                                print(day,eventName)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: The warning appears on the line "if let events = json["events"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]"

Comment: Check with option left click on json to see what type Xcode thinks the variable has, both with and without the import

Answer (score 0):

```
if let events = json["events"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
```

You probably have a string in the JSON, whereas you are trying to cast it to a dictionary, which won't work.

Put a breakpoint here and examine to see the contents of your JSON to verify.

Comment: I simplified my JSON to the following: {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
]}  It works just fine and returns the correct values to the console until I import the AWSSNS framework... then it fails as described above.

Comment: I get the warning as soon as I uncomment the import AWSSNS framework... so it hasn't parsed anything as yet because it isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

`"-[__NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"`

I don't think your problem come from JSON. If you can parse JSON, it's mean no problem with JSON. Check `selector`.